# API: Custom 404 not found error response structure

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

Considering this url: http://example.com/users/1/post/2/likes.

How can I correctly define structure of my 404 response, showing which item is not found? user, post or likes?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Are you using a rewrite rule that converts that to a PHP URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can send an HTTP status code using the `header()` function, by starting the header with the status code number, followed by the message to send to the user.

```
header("404 " + $message);
```

The code that processes the parameters can determine which item isn't found, and put that into `$message`.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by message? By the way I'm returning a json object as result, why shouldn't I put this info there?

Comment: `$message` would contain something like `user is missing`.

Comment: You asked how to put the information about which column is missing in the 404 response. Why would you use a 404 response if you're sending JSON? Just put status information in the JSON: `{ "success": false, "error": "user is missing"}`

Comment: `"error": "user is missing"` is a sentence. What if my api sends Italian translation of this error. How frontend can detect which item is missing? Should frontend parse every possible messages?

Comment: You could send a more structured JSON, like `{success: false, missing_fields: ["users", "post"]}`

Comment: If this is the structure you suggest, please update the answer :)

Comment: I answered the question you asked, which was how to send a message in the 404 response. If you want to know how to put a message in a JSON response, you should post a new question.